# Ssh error - should I change env.sh?

Tags: roslaunch, ssh, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am attempting to ssh into a turtlebot3 from my ubuntu 16.04 and launch turtlebot_bringup after that. Although the ssh is successful, I am getting the following error when the script tries to start the nodes:

```
error launching on [10.1.xxx.xx-0, uri http://turtlebot:34746/]: No route to host
Launch of the following nodes most likely failed: rosserial_python/serial_node.py, hls_lfcd_lds_driver/hlds_laser_publisher, turtlebot3_bringup/turtlebot3_diagnostics
```

Here's my launch script:

```
<launch>
<!-- ssh into bot and launch bringup -->    
<!-- Robot1 -->
   <!-- may need to remove ns from group tag-->
   <group ns="bot1">
       <param name="tf_prefix" value="bot1_tf" />
       <!-- Machine tag applies to any nodes/includes that come after it in the same scope -->
       <!-- default=true sets this machine as the default to assign nodes to within the scope -->
       <machine name="bot1" address="10.1.xx.xx" user="xxxxx" password="xxxxxx" default="true" env-loader="~/catkin_ws/devel/env.sh"/>
      
       <!-- Instead of including turtlebot3_robot.launch, include everything that is in it-->
       <!-- <include file="$(find turtlebot3_bringup)/launch/turtlebot3_robot.launch"/> -->
       <include file="$(find turtlebot3_bringup)/launch/turtlebot3_core.launch"/>
       <include file="$(find turtlebot3_bringup)/launch/turtlebot3_lidar.launch"/>        
       <!-- add machine name to diagnostics? machine="bot1" -->
       <node machine="bot1" pkg="turtlebot3_bringup" type="turtlebot3_diagnostics" name="turtlebot3_diagnostics" output="screen" />
   </group>
</launch>
```

Do I need to edit the env.sh file or something along those lines? I am using the standard generated one from catkin_ws/devel. Thanks!

env.sh as it stands currently (all values taken directly from ssh printenv):

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# generated from catkin/cmake/templates/env.sh.in

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
  /bin/echo "Usage: env.sh COMMANDS"
  /bin/echo "Calling env.sh without arguments is not supported anymore. Instead spawn a subshell and source a setup file manually."
  exit 1
fi

# ensure to not use different shell type which was set before
CATKIN_SHELL=sh

# source setup.sh from same directory as this file
_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(cd "`dirname "$0"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
. "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"

export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.1.xx.xx:11311
export PYTHONPATH=/home/raspberry/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/raspberry/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
export ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
export ROS_IP=10.1.xx.xx
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
export PATH=/home/raspberry/bin:/home/raspberry/.local/bin:/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
export ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/catkin_ws


exec "$@"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297947/ssh-error---should-i-change-env.sh?/) by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-07-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-07-20**:
Have you tried to individually launch the different node listed from the turtlebot ? Then from your PC ?
Also try to check the permissions of your sensors/actuators : `ls -l /dev/`

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-20**:
Hi there, and thanks for your reply! I used the command suggested and saw that everything on the turtlebot seems to have root access. I did notice that the ports being access for the launch, such as /dev/ttyACM0 and /dev/ttyUSB0 , also have "dailout" next to root instead of root root like the others

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-07-20**:
Dialout means that toi have access to the input from/dev si that's normal
Have you tried to launch each node separatly ?

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-20**:
I have confirmed that I can launch all the nodes individually after ssh-ing into the bot. Also , instead of `connection refused` , I am now getting a `No route to host` error. (question updated to reflect this)

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-07-20**:
Okay so it's probably @ahendrix 's first suggestion, can you print the value of `ROS_MASTER_URI`and `ROS_HOSTNAME` from your pc and the turtlebot please ?
(Using `echo $ROS_MASTER_URI`

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-20**:
echo ROS_MASTER_URI returns the same value for bot and pc, and as in env.sh. ROS_HOSTNAME returns nothing, and I have specified ROS_IP in my env.sh file as stated in the bot's printenv. ROS_IP is the same as in the machine tag of my launch file. I edited the question to include env.sh, Thank you!!

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-20**:
Got it figured out! Turns out it was a simple i.p. change that needed to be made in /etc/hosts. Thank you so much for all your suggestions! If anyone else is looking for this, the exact command is `sudo nano /etc/hosts`

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-07-20**:
Can you detail what you changed exactly in `/etc/hosts` to help other people ?

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-20**:
Of course! For me it was a very brief file - there is a line with the IP associated with whatever the Turtlebot’s name is. For me, that IP was pointing to a different Turtlebot, so simply changing it to the Turtlebot’s IP - 10.1.xx.xx - did the trick. Thank you so much again for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Connection refused` means that it couldn't establish any connection to the remote machine. There are a few common things that could cause this:

- Incorrect IP address
- SSH server isn't running
- No network connection between computers (cable unplugged, wifi down, etc)

I would start by trying to ssh to the remote machine manually by running:

```
ssh xxxxx@10.1.xx.xx
```

Establish that SSH works with that command before you try to troubleshoot roslaunch further.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-19**:
Thank you so much for your answer! Yes, ssh user@10.1.xxx.xx works perfectly, where user is the same as what I have stated in my machine  tag. Is it possible that I have done the machine tag wrong?